# Performance of Google Tag Manager Event Listeners compared to direct code implementation

Tags: performance, google-tag-manager, dom-events

The Google Tag Manager allows to setup several different types of event listeners as described here:
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3415369?hl=en

As I understand, if the rule matches (for e.g. "All Sites") and the tag is beeing triggered, GTM registers an event-listener listening for all link and/or button clicks, so that you can use those events, to trigger other rules / tags.

Assuming that I want to track clicks on several buttons and links on a page, what is the more performant solution?

a) using the approach proposed in the document above,

b) manually register a click event via code and send data with dataLayer.push() to GTM ?

Comment: I believe your assumption is wrong. They can just register one listener at the document level and intercept all events there.

Comment: @Eduardo yes, that's what I mean. Corrected the question.

Comment: There is still a wrong assumption though, that it would make any measurable difference whether you register it manually or not... The only option with a measurable performance benefit is when you don't use GTM at all and don't even load the tracking scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Using the built in listener for clicks would be better.

What happens is when you use a GTM click listener it listens for clicks that matches your trigger and sends your data, and no code change is required to set this up

while using the code implementation you would have to change the code, push data with event into dataLayer and make a trigger in gtm to listen for that event to fire your tag.

So in conclusion using the gtm listener would be better because its less time consuming, easy and has version control as well

Hope this help :)